# Regular expression for date object string

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript the date object give me following string.

```
var dateString=new Date();
console.log(dateString);//logs this 'Mon Jul 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'
```

Is there any regular expression to validate a string which is of this date format?
I am new to javascript please help.

Comment: Why would you need to validate the string?

Comment: I think [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) will be a correct way to parse that string.

Comment: My advice is that you don't even try. Dates are hard. There're libraries for that.

Comment: `/^(?:Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) (?:[0-2][0-9]|3[01]) \d{4} (?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[012345][0-9]:[012345][0-9] GMT\+0530 \(India Standard Time\)$/` Not true validation though, and you have said what you mean by `validate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Date.parse()` to test the string:

```
function isDate(str){ return !isNaN( Date.parse( str ) ); }
```

Testing:

```
isDate( 'Mon Jul 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' ); // true
isDate( '' ); // false
isDate( 1 ); // false

isDate( '2015-07-01' ); // true
isDate( '1 July 2015' ); // true
isDate( '1st July 2015' ); // false

// ISO 8601 Dates:
isDate( '2015-07-01T12:30:50' ) // true
isDate( '2015-07-01T12:30:50Z' ); // true 
isDate( '2015-07-01T12:30:50+01:00' ); // true 
isDate( '2015-07-01T12:30:50-01:00' ); // true
isDate( '2015-07-01 12:30:50' ) // false 
isDate( '2015-07-01T12:30:50+1:00' ); // false
```

Comment: On further testing, `Date.parse( 'abc-12345' );` returns `NaN` on Firefox, IE9 and IE11 but returns the date `12345-01-01T00:00:00Z` on Chrome (and Node.js) so there is inconsistencies in their date handling.

Comment: Anyway I changed my approach of dealing with dates. Thanks a ton for your help.